# Ninject to StructureMap

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject, structuremap, doi

I am looking to convert following  code to StructureMap:

```
private Mock<MembershipProvider> MockMembership = new Mock<MembershipProvider>();

private StandardKernel GetIoCKernel()
{
    var modules = new IModule[]
    {
        new InlineModule(
            new Action<InlineModule>[]
            {
                m => m.Bind<MembershipProvider>()
                    .ToConstant(MockMembership.Object),
            })
    };

    return new StandardKernel(modules);
}
```

Mainly I am looking for the equivalent of the `ToConstant` method in StructureMap. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Explain what ToConstant does in Ninject and I'll tell you the equivalent in StructureMap.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `ToConstant()` means "use this instance", the equivalent in StructureMap is:

```
For<MembershipProvider>().Use(MockMembership.Object);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since ToConstant does not mean singleton, you want this:

```
private StandardKernel GetIoCKernel()
{
    return new Container(c => c.For<MembershipProvider>().Use(() => MockMembership.Object));
}
```

When you passing a delegate into For(), StructureMap will default to transient.

Comment: ToConstant (or any of its To* siblings) doesnt imply a scope (and the default is transient). Having said that, that distinction is pretty moot given it'll always be the same object

Comment: If you instruct the container "everytime I request an object that implements this interface/type, I want you to give me this specific instance", then I would call that a singleton.

Comment: i don't see For and Use with latest version of SM 2.5.3

Comment: The latest version is 2.6.1, get it here: https://github.com/downloads/structuremap/structuremap/StructureMap2.6.1.zip